# cURL Error: Operation timed out after 15001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received woocomerce API

Tags: laravel, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, laravel-8, woocommerce-rest-api

Facing cURL Error: Operation timed out after 15001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received issues with Woocomerce API to create products.

I am using the Laravel package i.e  https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce
It was working fine and creating products but suddenly it stopped working and start throwing PHP errors.

**Below are the method that I am using to create a book on Woocomerce from laravel Controller:**

```
public function addProductToWC(Request $request)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $response = '';     
    if ($request->isMethod('post')){
        if(!empty($request->get('book_id'))){
            $book = Book::find($request->get('book_id'));
            $coverImgPath = base_path('public/customize_book/'.Session::get('cover_image'));

            if (file_exists($coverImgPath)) {
                $imageurl = url('/public/customize_book/'.Session::get('cover_image'));
            } else {
                $imageurl = url('/images/'.$book->bookimage);
            }
            if(!empty($book->id)){
                $data = [
                    'name' => $book->title,
                    'type' => 'simple',
                    'regular_price' => number_format($request->get('book_price')),
                    'description' => (!empty($book->description) ? $book->description :''),
                    'short_description' => 'Simple product short description.',
                    'categories' => [
                        [
                            'id' => 1
                        ]
                    ],
                    'images' => [
                        [
                            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
                        ],
                        [
                            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                
                $product = Product::create($data);
                
                if($product['id']){
                    $response = array('error' => false,'code' => '200', 'data' => array('product_id' => $product['id'], 'message' => 'Product created successfully.'));
                }else{
                    $response = array('error' => true,'code' => '401', 'data' => array('product_id' => $product['id'], 'message' => 'Product syncing failed please try again later.'));                 
                }
            }else{
                $response = array('error' => true,'code' => '401','message' => 'Invalid book detail please try again.');
            }
        }else{
            $response = array('error' => true,'code' => '401','message' => 'Invalid book detail please try again.');            
        }
    }else{
        $response = array('error' => true,'code' => '401','message' => 'Invalid method please try again.');         
    }
    // return response
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the composer.json at https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce/blob/master/composer.json, I can see that they are using the woocommerce client `"automattic/woocommerce": "^3.0"` This defaults to a **request** timeout of 15 seconds, hence why `set_time_limit(0);` didn't fix the issue.

When using it directly you'd set the timeout in the options

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    env('MGF_WOOCOMMERCE_API_URL'), // Your store URL
    env('MGF_WOOCOMMERCE_API_KEY'), // Your consumer key
    env('MGF_WOOCOMMERCE_API_SECRET'), // Your consumer secret
    [
        'timeout' => 120, // SET TIMOUT HERE
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    ]
);
```

Looking at the library source https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce/blob/master/src/WooCommerceApi.php

```
        $this->client = new Client(
            config('woocommerce.store_url'),
            config('woocommerce.consumer_key'),
            config('woocommerce.consumer_secret'),
            [
                'version'           => 'wc/'.config('woocommerce.api_version'),
                'wp_api'            => config('woocommerce.wp_api_integration'),
                'verify_ssl'        => config('woocommerce.verify_ssl'),
                'query_string_auth' => config('woocommerce.query_string_auth'),
                'timeout'           => config('woocommerce.timeout'),
            ]
        );
```

It looks like the timeout is coming from `woocommerce.timeout` in your Laravel config file.